# How to create a Direct2D factory

Tags: c++, directx, factory, direct2d

I am creating a Direct2D application and the API overview page says the first step is to create a factory... well I tried that with this function

```
D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED, &factory);
```

but it gives the error

```
Error   62  error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _D2D1CreateFactory@16 referenced in function "long __cdecl D2D1CreateFactory(enum D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE,struct _GUID const &,void * *)" (?D2D1CreateFactory@@YAJW4D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE@@ABU_GUID@@PAPAX@Z
```

I am calling the D2D1CreateFactory function from within the WinMain function.

This is how I initialized the factory pointer

```
ID2D1Factory *factory;
```

These are the Include and Library Directories

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Include
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Lib\x86
```

I have experience with direct3D so I am familiar with devices and render targets, but I was under the impression that for direct2D the factory comes first so I haven't created any devices, render targets, etc...

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you actually tell the linker which libraries to link? Specifying only the location of the libraries is not enough.

Comment: This same configuration has worked for 3d applications in the past... unless there is a difference in specifying directories between 2d and 3d applications it should work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to add to your code this directive.

```
#pragma comment(lib, "d2d1.lib")
```

It will link `d2d1.lib` to your object code.
You may use this directive to link to the other libs.